# Why is $\frac{a+1}{p^{\epsilon a}}$ bounded by a constant C that only depends on $\epsilon$?

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Why is $\frac{a+1}{p^{\epsilon a}}$ bounded by a constant C that only depends on $\epsilon$ ?
Here $a \geq 1$ is an integer ,$p$ is any prime and $\epsilon > 0$.

I tried considering the logarithm $\log\frac{a+1}{p^{\epsilon a}} = \log(a+1) - \epsilon a \log(p)$ but I would need to show this quantity is bounded above by a constant that depends only on $\epsilon$. Intuitively speaking with $p$ and $\epsilon$ fixed I think this quantity is bounded above for all $a$ since I think its negative for sufficiently large $a$, but I'm not sure how to argue this rigorously.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $\epsilon$ had better be positive...

Comment: Edited to include what I tried.

Comment: Hint: if you keep $a$ and $\epsilon$ fixed, the largest outcome is always for $p=2$.

Comment: Thanks, now its clear why the constant wouldn't need to depend on $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,
$$\frac{a+1}{p^{\epsilon a}}\leq \frac{a+1}{2^{\epsilon a}},$$
since replacing $p$ with $2$ only decreases the denominator. We claim that $(a+1)/2^{\epsilon a}$ is eventually decreasing in $a$, which will show that it is bounded above. To do this, it suffices to show that, for large enough $a$,
$$\frac{a+1}{2^{\epsilon a}}\geq \frac{a+2}{2^{\epsilon(a+1)}}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$2^\epsilon\geq \frac{a+2}{a+1}=1+\frac1{a+1}.$$
Since the left side is some constant greater than $1$ (assuming $\epsilon>0$) and the right side goes to $1$ as $a\to\infty$, this is true for large enough $a$.

In fact, the maximum is reached near $a=\frac{1}{2^\epsilon-1}$, and you can use this to figure out how the constant $C$ varies in $\epsilon$.